# Upgrade MySQL 5.0.88 to 5.1.69

Tags: ssh, fedora, mysql

I am upgrading my MySQL installation on a Fedora 10 (and 14) box (in test first.) I have made a system image (it is a VM) and have downloaded MySQL Server Community 5.1.69-1 from the MySQL site.

Once downloaded, and placed in the `/usr/etc` folder, I ran the following:

```
[root@padev ~]# cd /usr/etc
[root@padev etc]# ls -l
total 20336
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20799393 2013-04-30 14:34 MySQL-server-community-5.1.69-1.rhel5.i386.rpm
[root@padev etc]# rpm -Uvh MySQL-server-community-5.1.69-1.rhel5.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-community-5.1.69-1.rhel5.i386
    MySQL conflicts with mysql-5.0.88-1.fc10.x86_64
    MySQL-server conflicts with mysql-server-5.0.88-1.fc10.x86_64
[root@padev etc]#
```

I thought that the `-U` portion would invoke an upgrade and thus the second and third items in the error would be disregarded. I don't know how to upgrade `libgcc` either.

Comment: You really ought to upgrade to CentOS or RHEL or a modern Fedora. But other than that, your best hope is probably to compile MySQL from source. Assuming that libgcc_s isn't available for F10 (which I'd guess uses an older version of gcc, etc.)

Comment: I appreciate all the input thus far and I really wish upgrading OS versions was an option but it is not at this point in time. For that reason, I ask that answers pertain to the question of upgrading MySQL itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully update:

```
yum --enablerepo remi install  mysql-server
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use a supported version of Fedora -- namely 17 or 18. If you need long term support, try CentOS. Second, is there a reason you don't install MySQL with the package manager?

Comment: I would love to be on the most recent release of Fedora, but upgrading isn't really an option at this point because we are so out of date I wouldn't trust that, after upgrading, out web application would function as expected.

As for the Package Manager, that is a UI based tool, correct? our Fedora installs have no UI.

Comment: It's not a UI-based tool, it's a command line utility named yum. CentOS also uses it.

Comment: Oh! Yeah... I used YUM to update but it just went from 5.0.77 to 5.0.88 and won't go up from there. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you're using an old and unsupported version of Fedora.

Comment: That would really cause me not to be able to upgrade MySQL? What about upgrading through the RPM method as mentioned above... How can i get past those dependency issues?

Comment: Don't even think about it. MySQL depends on other system components that are hideously outdated.

Comment: Remember though, i'm just trying to update to MySQL 5.1 to fix some FTS issues that were in 5.0.xx... I got past the libgcc dependency, but now it just saying that there are conflicts with the existing MySQL version. Is there a specific way to UPDATE rather than try installing side by side?

Answer (score 2):

A *web application* running on a hopelessly outdated operating system with *no* support... migrate that to a new version of CentOS ASAP. And in the process check carefully that no unauthorized changes have been made.

Be careful, your uninvited guests might get angry, and I wouldn't like to cross  a mob of that size.